# Primefaces Datatable Date column filtering

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

How can I filter Date column in Datatable in dd//mm/yyyy pattern ?
I'm using Primefaces 5.2 Community edition.

```
<p:column sortBy="#{user.date}" styleClass="date"
    filterBy="#{user.date}" id="date">

        <h:outputText value="#{user.date}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </h:outputText>
        <p:watermark for="@(.date)" value="#{msg['dateOfBirth']}" />

</p:column>
```

Filtering without a converter works, but with the converter is does not work anymore

Comment: Since PrimeFaces 5.0, any input component can be placed inside `<f:facet name="filter">` which acts as a column filter. Filtering a result list by dates is then no longer different than filtering it by using other type of values.

Comment: Yes there is no problem in filtering, but the real problem is how to filter in dd/mm/yyyy pattern

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me.

```
<p:column headerText="Data " filterBy="#{user.date}">
    <h:outputText value="#{user.date}" />
```

But may be im not geting whats ur real problem is.

Edit.

I copy pasted ur code and it works fine for me...

```
<p:column sortBy="#{odczyt.data_odczytu}" 
filterBy="#{odczyt.data_odczytu}" id="date">
    <h:outputText value="#{odczyt.data_odczytu}">
        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </h:outputText>
    <p:watermark for="@(.date)" value="#{msg['dateOfBirth']}" />
```

You must remember that the filter doesnt see your date in converted format but in orginal form that comes from your backing bean.
So when u have a date in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format and use converter 'pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"', in filter field u must use same pattern as original bean format, for example '2015-05-03'.

Comment: Why downvoted? As i said i have no problem to filter date with just this. What type is ur 'date'? I use timestamp

Comment: Looks like it does as long as there is timezone set for convertDateTime.      `<p:column headerText="Data zuzycia" filterBy="#{odczyt.data_zuzycia}">
       <h:outputText value="#{odczyt.data_zuzycia}" >
        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" />
       </h:outputText>
      </p:column>` and in web.xml  `<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>`

Answer (score -3):

Don't format date in view but rather convert and format as string the backing bean.

view

```
 <p:column sortBy="#{user.dateAsString}" styleClass="date" 
      filterBy="#{user.dateAsString}" id="date">
    <h:outputText value="#{user.dateAsString}">
 </p:column>
```

backing bean

```
public String getDateAsString() {
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Bad choice, PrimeFaces has way enough options to really filter on dates

Comment: @Kukeltje why not show us your answer then?  My solution worked much easier for me than trying to use PF filters on actual dates in the view.

Comment: Use a filter facet.  Input can calendar component. No need to add view responsibility (format) to your bean. No need to post an answer for me since this is in the PrimeFaces showcase

Comment: @Kukeltje A link to the showcase example you are referring to would be beneficial. I don't see one filtering on Dates. Their example for custom filter function is for prices http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml .  I've used custom filter function on other data but just found my solution above to be much simple to implement for dates. Also, by using a String representation, end users can type a partial date such as "11/" and show only items with November dates or "/27" and show items due on the 27th day.